# dplyr groups not working with dollar sign data$column syntax

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I'm looking to find the min and max values of a column for each group:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(mtcars$cyl) %>%
  summarize(
    min_mpg = min(mtcars$mpg),
    max_mpg = max(mtcars$mpg)
  )
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   `mtcars$cyl` min_mpg max_mpg
#          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1            4    10.4    33.9
# 2            6    10.4    33.9
# 3            8    10.4    33.9
```

It works for the most part and the format of the dataset looks good. However, it gives the min and max of the entire dataset, not of each individual group.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I feel that that is a common-enough question these days, but I cannot find a good "dupe" question/answer. (Not to mention it's not easy to search for `"$"`-centric questions.) Do you know of any? It might be nice to add that to [tag:r-faq]?

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you! This worked indeed. And this will definitely help me in the future when using dplyr.

Comment: Strongly agree about adding it to r-faq. I'll convert my comment to an answer. But is SO search acting up? I'm not getting any results searching the `[r-faq]` tag right now, though I can search by question title and find FAQs...

Comment: @r2evans but now the real challenge, if this is to be a FAQ, is to make it as searchable as possible

Comment: I suggest inclusion of "dollar-sign" or "dollar", that was a search attempt of mine (not-very-successful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `$` inside `dplyr` functions, they expect unquoted column names.

`mtcars$mpg` is specifically referencing the whole column form the original input data frame, not the grouped the grouped tibble coming out of `group_by`. Change your code to remove the `data$` and it will work:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(
    min_mpg = min(mpg),
    max_mpg = max(mpg)
  )
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#     cyl min_mpg max_mpg
#   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     4    21.4    33.9
# 2     6    17.8    21.4
# 3     8    10.4    19.2
```

(Not to mention it's a lot less typing!)