# How to count unique values per subject ID in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has subject ID in one column and responses in another. Every subject ID is repeated 45 times because there were 45 trials subjects responded to. I am trying to find how many unique responses each subject had in the task (so through those 45 trials).

```
BehVari<-individData%>%
group_by(individData$SubID)%>% 
summarise(count = n_distinct(individData$Rating.1))
BehVari
```

This is the code I was trying to use to group by subject ID and then get the the number of unique responses per participant. The issue is that it is reporting the same number of unique responses for everyone, which isn’t the case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr groups not working with dollar sign data$column syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806117/dplyr-groups-not-working-with-dollar-sign-datacolumn-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to remove the `data$` as this will extract the full column

```
library(dplyr)
BehVari<- individData%>%
group_by(SubID)%>% 
summarise(count = n_distinct(Rating.1))
BehVari
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
library("dplyr")
individData %>% group_by(SubID) %>% summarise(Count = n_distinct(Rating.1))
```